# Can't alter element's html after selecting it with querySelector

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the html in a div using querySelector, but it's not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="test">

    <p>par1</p>
    <p>par2</p>
    <p>par3</p>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var d = document.querySelector('.test');

var d.innerHTML = '<p>works</p>';
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GTjmX/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `var` keyword before `d.innerHTML`, it is a property, not a variable.
The code:

```
var d = document.querySelector('.test');

d.innerHTML = '<p>works</p>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't define the variable again, it's:

```
var d = document.querySelector('.test');

    d.innerHTML = '<p>works</p>';
```